# Stripping down Phonenumber (mobile)

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, stripping

Is there a function or a easy way to strip down phone numbers to a specific format?

Input can be a number (mobile, different country codes)

maybe

```
+4917112345678
+49171/12345678
0049171 12345678
```

or maybe from another country

```
004312345678
+44...
```

Im doing a

```
$mobile_new = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$mobile);
```

to kill everything else than a number, because i need it in the format 49171 (without + or 00 at the beginning), but i need to handle if a 00 is inserted first or maybe someone uses +49(0)171 or or inputs a 0171 (needs to be 49171.

so the first numbers ALWAYS need to be countryside without +/00 and without any (0) between.

can someone give me an advice on how to solve this?

Comment: If the user inputs `0171.....` or anything else not starting with a `+` or `00` you can only GUESS what the countryspecific prefix would be. Or do you want to make `49` the default for this case?

Comment: Thats right. Im going to add a dropdown for CC i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:^(?:00|\+|\+\d{2}))|\/|\s|\(\d\)
```

to match most of your cases and simply replace them with nothing. For example:

```
$mobile = "+4917112345678";
$mobile_new = preg_replace("/(?:^(?:00|\+|\+\d{2}))|\/|\s|\(\d\)/","",$mobile);
echo $mobile_new;
//output: 4917112345678
```

[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH8vT7/2)

Explanation:

I'm making use of `OR` here, matching each of your cases one by one:

1. `(?:^(?:00|\+|\+\d{2}))` matches `00`, `+` or `+` followed by two numbers at the beginning of your string
2. `\/` matches a `/` anywhere in the string
3. `\s` matches a whitspace anywhere in the string (it matches the newline in the regex101 demo, but I suppose you match each number on its own)
4. `\(\d\)` matches a number enclosed in brackets anywhere in the string

The only case not covered by this regex is the input format `01712345678`, as you can only take a guess what the country specific prefix can be. If you want it to be `49` by default, then simply replace each input starting with a single `0` with the `49`:

```
$mobile = "01712345678";
$mobile_new = preg_replace("/^0/","49",$mobile);
echo $mobile_new;
//output: 491712345678
```

Comment: Working fine! And your right.. the cc is needed for the script to work properly, so if someone forgets the cc, no action is required :)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `(49)\(?([0-9]{3})[\)\s\/]?([0-9]{8})` will split number in three groups:

- 49 - country code
- 3 digits - area code
- 8 digits - number

After match you can construct clean number just concatnating them by `\1\2\3`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tE5iY3/1

If this not suits you then please explain more precisely what you want with test input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at LibPhoneNumber by Google and its port for PHP.
It has support for many formats and countries and is well-maintained. Better not to figure this out yourself.

https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

```
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
$usNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse("+1 650 253 0000", "US");
```

Comment: looks nice! Im going to implement this in a later update! THX!